# How a custom component can be imported in Cakephp MiddleWare Class?

Tags: php, oop, cakephp, components, middleware

I have a generic `OAuthComponent` with a

```
namespace App\Controller\Component
```

my Middleware Class has a namespace

```
namespace App\Middleware;
```

How can I use a custom Component in the Middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't because a component relies on the controller. Loading a component in a middleware is completely **wrong** and goes against the architecture and design patterns of the framework.

### Cake < 3.6

Refactor the component in an an object that has no other dependency than request and response and then create a middleware that will use this object.

### Cake >= 3.6 & 4.0

It looks like you want to do something with auth, so for newer versions of CakePHP use the identifiers of the authentication plugin instead of using an auth component at all. The plugin implements a middleware and the specific authentication mechanics are abstraced into identifiers.

https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html

Comment: Or, better yet, build the logic as an Identifier class for the Cake Authentication plugin  Cake has an Authentication middleware that you can leverage for this: https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html

Comment: This is new and I wrote this plugin. ;) Going to add it to the answer.

Comment: Can you use the Authentication plugin within another plugin's Middleware?
I want to write a logging Middleware, and log the user (if any is logged in).

Comment: You can, read about how middlewares work. The manual has a whole section about middlewares and you can find information explaining the concept of http middlewares on Google or read the documents provided by the PSR group.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply :-)
I kept getting null on a logged in user. Ther reason for this, was the order of the the MiddlewareQueue. I've change it (```$middlewareQueue->prepend()``` instead of ```$middlewareQueue->add()```, so that Authentication and Authorization are executed first.
After that, the identity is set and available in the new LoggingMiddleware:

```php
        $identity = $request->getAttribute('identity');
```

Answer (score -1):

import your component first

```
use App\Controller\Component\DateComponent;
```

then import Component Registry

```
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
```

then declare it into new variable then call the component function

```
$registry = new ComponentRegistry();
$date = new DateComponent($registry);
```

Comment: This does not work reliably because most components rely on a controller object in the ComponentRegistry, which is not supplied here.  The ComponentRegistry constructor *can* take a null parameter for controller, but most components will still need it in order to operate.